# Chances of winning a raffle?

Tags: probability

If there is a raffle going on and tickets for the raffle are $20, Prizes are as follows.
1st = 1000
2nd = 200
3rd = 100

If there are only 1000 tickets for sale, how do I go about working out the expectation of how much I would win.
 **Assuming that once a ticket is taken out it is not put back in.**

Im assuming that my expectation is 1/1000 for 3rd prize, 1/999 for 2nd and 1/998 for third and thats it? It seems too simple of an answer for such a high mark question on one of my tests.. :\

Comment: Why not $\frac1{1000}$ for the first then? If one of $1000$ raffles is linked with some prize then the probability to win that prize if $\frac1{1000}$. No matter what prize (first, second or third).

Comment: Because when the first ticket is drawn, theres only 999 tickets left to be drawn.

Comment: Suppose they draw third, then second then the top prize.  Should this affect the results?  Should it?

Comment: Your $\frac1{998}$ is not the probability of winning the third prize. It is the probability of winning the third prize **under the extra condition of not winning one of the other prizes**.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the expectation is $\frac{1}{1000}$ for each prize, giving you expected earnings of $\$ 1.30$.

You can see this more concretely as follows: In total, $\$1300$ will be given away to $1000$ people.  Each has the same expectation.

Comment: Oh what i ment to mention was that each ticket is thrown out once it is drawn.

Comment: @MichaelMariani Do you agree with the second line in this answer (...1300...to...1000...each has the same expectation)?

Comment: It definitely makes sense, But Its more 100 will be given to 1000, 200 to 999 and 1000 to 998.

Comment: Picture this:  they pick all 1000 tickets, one at a time, and arrange them in a row.  What's the probability that your ticket will be in the first of 100 slots, the second of 1000 slots, or the third of the 1000 slots?

Answer (score 0):

Why not the following?

$$
Expectation = +(1000-20)*1/1000+(200-20)*/1/1000+(100-20)*1/1000-20*(997/1000)
$$

$$
Expectation = -18.70
$$

Comment: thats the way i ended up doing it, it comes up with the same result as above thanks for the help :)